# Is it possible to make a frameless PWA?

Tags: javascript, web, progressive-web-apps

Something that slightly bugs me about progressive web apps on the desktop is that they retain the browser chrome/frame when you "install" them/pin them to your desktop. I love that the menu bar, bookmarks, etc. are gone, since the point is to feel like a native app rather than something in my browser, but the frame feels like one last thing standing in the way of a truly native feel. For comparison, consider the "frameless window" concept from [nw.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Frameless-window) or [Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/frameless-window.md).

So is there any way, e.g. an option in the `manifest.json` file, to hide the frame as well?

My research indicates that the answer is currently "no", so I guess a followup question would be, has there been any discussion of it? Are there concerns preventing it, or has it just not come up at all? Any info would be great.

**Edit:** To be clearer, I don't mean simply launching in a separate window with its own icon, that's just what desktop installed PWAs are. I mean removing/hiding the title bar as well, with the app icon and name and the minimize/maximize/close buttons, plus the thin frame border that runs around the outside of the entire window. All this stuff:

[image: lodash desktop PWA with browser frame selected]

Comment: Not sure about other browsers, but Chrome has an experimental flag for exactly this... chrome://flags/#enable-desktop-pwas

Comment: @phuzi Nice! So when you're using that flag, how do you enable frameless mode or whatever?

Comment: I think using the flag should enable launching of an "installed" PWA in a chromeless window. Haven't tried it myself but that is what's supposed to happen.

Comment: ooh I see. No, that one I already knew about, and actually that's just what I mean: it doesn't launch in an entirely chromeless window, it's just a stripped down window that only has the title bar with the logo, app name, and minimize/maximize/close buttons, plus a narrow-ish border around the window, same as what you get when the browser window is not maximized. I'd like to get rid of all of that if possible, for a fully native feel.

Comment: Hmm, looking at your screenshot, I'd say that it looks exactly like any other windows application. What you're asking for would look more like a splash screen to me.

Comment: Also, given that the flag mentioned above is still experimental, there may be more than a little wait even if the option is available in the future.

Comment: A splash screen would be one use case, but many newer apps I've seen are opting to hide the native frame and implement their own simple chrome for a more minimal feel. I've done this before in an nw.js application, and it's a very nice aesthetic. Though I do take your point that many/most native desktop applications have the same sort of frame, so it's not really a barrier to the native feel

Comment: There is also a proposal for a 'Borderless' display mode (https://github.com/WICG/manifest-incubations/blob/gh-pages/borderless-explainer.md) without any browser-mandated window frame, but it's currently only targeting Isolated Web Apps [2], which are still in development. [2]: https://github.com/WICG/isolated-web-apps

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is `display` in the manifest (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest#display).

`"display": "fullscreen"` indicates you want to completely hide the browser chrome.

However, support of specific display modes varies between browsers and platforms.
For example Windows 10 (via Edge) only supports `browser` and `standalone` right now, with support for `fullscreen` and `minimal-ui` coming in [Redstone 5](https://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-is-adding-new-display-modes-to-pwas-in-windows-10-redstone-5).

Answer (score 2):

Now there comes with a new mode: **window-controls-overlay**

[image]

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/display_override#values

See YouTube intro here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tj0_4pcrj7s&t=1114s

And also: https://web.dev/window-controls-overlay